# Can you dynamically switch databases using useDb?

Tags: mongoose

Is it possible to have the original connection point to a new database?

Basically I have one connection that I want to always use the same database and then I have a second that the database can be dynamic.

So:

```
global.db = mongoose.createConnection('mongodb://localhost:27017');
global.db1 = db.useDb('static');
global.db2 = db.useDb('dynamic');
```

and then elsewhere in the code be able to change db2 so it will point to a new database:

```
db2.useDb('newDb');
```